# VS 2022 SSIS project creation failed

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

When I try to create SSIS project I get this error: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

[image]

Can someone explain what's the problem? Does anyone use SSIS with VS 2022?

Extension version 1.3
VS 2022 Community Version 17.8.1

I've tried to repair/reinstall extension but with no success

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I tried all the solutions for StrongName validation with no success.

So I was going to try re-installing Microsoft Data Tools Integration Services when I noticed there was an update available.

I downloaded and installed the update and then I was able to create a SSIS project in VS2022 with no issues.